# HQL How to select records from table with multicondidions

Tags: hibernate, hql

Hello I want to select records in HQL from challengeEntity where un1 equals "a" or "b" and  un2 equals "a" or "b"

(un1=a||b)&&(un2=a||b)

This is (not working) my query

```
"from ChallengeEntity c where c.un1=a||b and c.un2=a||b"
```

Ill be very glad if someone can declare prepar query for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
 from ChallengeEntity c where (c.un1=a or c.un1=b) and (c.un2=a or c.un2=b)
```